# How to understand "cmpl $0x0, -0x30(%rbp)" / "je ..."

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, disassembly, att

[image]

This is the assembly code from my bomb lap question, I am stuck in phase2;
The bomb lab require us to find out the correct input based on assembly code or it will exploded.

From <+20> I know that %rbp -0x30(48) == 0 or it will call <+32> and explode the bomb; so %rbp = 48(DEC)

After that(+26) %rbp - 0x2c(44) must equal 1 or it will explode the bomb...
But since %rbp  = 48, the bomb will explode anywhere so I am confuse now...

I think I misunderstand the compl , je/jne  or how to calculate these things...

Comment: By getting to the "read_six_numbers". I know the input are 6 numbers with some kinds of patterns.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text.  Copy/paste from your terminal.

Comment: [don't put images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-0x30(%ebp)` doesn't mean to use the value `%ebp - 0x30`. It's a memory address to read from. The instruction (`cmpl`) has an `l` suffix, so it's dealing with a 4 byte quantity. So what's actually happening is that it reads a 4 byte number from the address `%ebp - 0x30` and checks whether it's zero.

(The `$` prefix means it's an immediate value, not an address. This is why `0x0` is taken literally and not dereferenced.)

Comment: Thank you so much! But now how can I know what is the value of %ebp since it just read the 4byte memory directly.  I know nothing about this.

Comment: @James Well, given that the code loads the address of `%ebp - 0x30` into `%rsi` (first argument) before calling `read_six_numbers`, I assume this is where `read_six_numbers` puts its results; i.e. it's the start of a buffer of 6 integers. This is consistent with the size 48 = 6 \* 8 (for six 8-byte integers) ... except that doesn't make sense because we're only comparing 4 byte integers. Hmm...

Comment: It's `%rbp`, not `%ebp`.  It's a 64-bit pointer (to 4 bytes of memory).  It's being used as a frame pointer in this function, so its upper 32 bits aren't all zero and `0x30(%ebp)` would segfault.

Comment: `-0x30(%rbp)` does exactly mean "use value `rbp - 0x30`" ... when used in `lea` instruction. Your first sentence is true for all (? I hope :) ) the other x86 instructions, when `-0x30(%rbp)` means value from memory. As the code snippet contains both `lea` and `cmp`, I think it's worth to explain both.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know value of `rbp` to defuse the bomb, it's used always in relative way to address certain portion of memory. It's set at the start by the sequence:

```
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    pushq   %r12
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $0x20, %rsp
```

Which does push old `rbp` value into stack (to preserve it), then sets `rbp` to current stack pointer value (`rsp`). So `(%rbp)` contains the old `rbp` now. Then another two registers `r12` and `rbx` are preserved by pushing them into stack (which makes now `rsp == rbp - 16`). And then `rsp` is adjusted one more time by subtracting 32, i.e. `rsp == rbp - 48`.

This is common pattern how to allocate memory space for local variables, i.e. any further `push` instruction will use memory below `rbp - 48`. Memory from `rbp - 48` up to `rbp - 17` (inc.) is undefined, free to use as "local variables" memory. Then at `rbp - 16` is stored in 8 bytes original `rbx` value, at `rbp - 8` is stored original `r12` value, and at `rbp` is stored old `rbp`. (I mean all the "rbp - x" to be used as memory addresses to address values in the memory)

Then your code calls input 6 numbers, which I guess means 32 bit integers (judging by the following code), so it provides it with address `rbp - 48`. 6*4 = 24 => the inputted values will be stored in memory from address `rbp - 48` up to (incl.) `rbp - 25`.

Note the gap of "unused memory" from `rbp - 24` up to `rbp - 17`, that's another 8 bytes of spare local storage, not used by the code you posted, that's very likely padding added by compiler to make the `rsp` correctly aligned before `callq read_six_numbers`.

So basically you don't need to know where exactly `rsp/rbp` points to, it's pointing to some valid stack memory (either that, or the code will crash, and the bomb will **NOT** explode ... a bit weird design :)))). You can pick any arbitrary value, like `0x8000` for `rsp` at start, and simulate the run with that. (i.e. the `<+11> leaq -0x30,(%rbp), %rsi` is then `rsi = 0x7FC8;` (0x8000 - 8 - 0x30).

Rest of what `-x(%rbp)` means in various instructions (pay attention to the `lea` vs `<any other instruction>` semantics difference of "memory operand" usage, the `lea` does only the memory address calculation, while other instructions just start by that, using the calculated address to access actual value stored in memory) is described in the other answer + comment. Plus use the x86 instruction reference guide and read through some tutorials few more times, until it will make sense.